# Callback error handler didn't stop execute function

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to develop an API post, in middle execution I have validation such as check name already in use or not. I set error handler callback, it successfully send response 'Already registered', but when I checked to CLI, it show error

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

I dont know whats wrong, I use this error handler in the past and it seems look ok.

Here is my code in router:

```
createUserAccount: async function (req, res) {
    const programData = req.body;
    try {
        await service.create(programData, function (code, err, result) {
            if (err) {
                if(code === 409){
                    res.status(HTTPSTATUS.CONFLICT).send(err.message);
                } else {
                    res.status(HTTPSTATUS.BAD_REQUEST).send(err.message);
                }
            } else {
                res.status(HTTPSTATUS.CREATED).json(result);
            }
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(HTTPSTATUS.BAD_REQUEST).json("Failed.");
    }
```

Here is my function in my service:

```
const config = require('@configs/config.json')
const sequelize = require('sequelize');
const SEQUELIZE = new sequelize(config[env]);

module.exports = {
    createAccount: async (name, password, callback) => {
        try {
            let check,
                institution_id;

            const checkName = await Profile.count(
                {
                    where: {
                        name: name
                    }
                }
            );

            //result checkName = 1
            if(checkName > 0){
                //then successfully execute this condition and

                return callback(409, 'Already registered.', null);
                //this show in console ----> POST /API/v1/user/profile 409 616.152 ms - 31
            }

            await Login.create({
                    username: email,
                    password: password
                }).then(resLogin => {

                    const response = {
                        id: resLogin.id,
                    }

                    callback(201, null, response);
                }).catch( error => {
                    callback(400, error, null);
                })
        } catch (e) {
            callback(400, e, null);
        }
    },

    create: async (payload, callback) => {
        let loginID = null;

        let {
            profile,
            address
        } = payload;

        let {
            name,
            email,
            password
        } = profile;

        try {
            await module.exports.createAccount(name, password, function (code, error, result) {
                if(error){
                    const res = {message: error};

                    //what I need is the execution is end in here
                    return callback(code, res, null);
                }

                loginID = result.id;
            });

            //but the fact is it still execute this whole function if got callback error from createAccount()

            let transaction = await SEQUELIZE.transaction();
            await Address.create(address, {transaction})
                .then( async resAddress => {
                    await transaction.commit();

                    return callback(201, null, resProfile);
                }).catch(async e  => {
                    return callback(400, e, null);
                })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            callback(e, null);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you share line number in which this error occurs. Also please check if you are calling callback() function multiple times in same request flow, I see that in some places return keyword is not used along with callback() call

Comment: @ssk I've updated the code, I add comment line. Yes I set callback multiple times, but it's called in different case/conditions. That's true. I dont know why, it's look like sometimes work sometimes not. Is there differential between `return callback();` and `callback(); return;`

Comment: You are passing around callbacks when you don't have to. You already are using `async` / `await` which is an improvement to usual callback workflow. If you do not want t o execute `Address.create`, unless the `createAccount` is successfull, you have to move it to the callback of `createAccount`.

Comment: @ssk move it? can you give me more description about move it?